# Чи можна назвати Поліну Пелагеєю?

Tags: синоніми, власні-назви

Якось довелося почути як дівчину Поліну одна бабуся кликала Палажка (те саме, що і Пелагея).

На [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D1%96%D0%BC%27%D1%8F)) я знайшов таку інформацію про походження імені Поліна:

> ...походить від грецького імені Аполлінарія, яке є похідною імені
> давньогрецького бога Аполлона, та означає «сонячна». Інша версія
> походження імені — від фр. Pauline («Полін», «Поліна») — французького
> варіанту імені Павлина.

Там же вказано, що споріднене ім'я - [Павлина](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0), яке немає нічого спільного із іменем Пелагея. Однак на тій же Вікіпедії читаємо:

> Святих під іменем Поліна немає як у Католицькій, так і у Православній
> церкві. Зазвичай хрестять Полін під іменами **Пелагея**, **Павла**,
> **Аполлінарія**.

Але наскільки я знаю, ім'я, дається при народженні, і те, яке дається при хрещенні, не завжди співпадають, а інколи й можуть бути зовсім різними.

Однак, на цьому [сайті](http://radka.in.ua/poradi/palajka-znachennia-imeni-pelageia-is.html#i) (а також [тут](http://supermg.com/ezoterika/znachennja-imeni-ljudini/19792-znachennja-imeni-pelageja-shho-oznachae-im-ja.html)) є інформація:

> **Зменшувальним ім’ям від Пелагея стане Поля, Полюся**.

Та не впевнений, що цим сайтам можна довіряти. Тому вирішив пошукати етимологію імені Пелагея, і ось що я знайшов ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%8F)) - ім'я Пелагея походить від д.грец. πέλαγος — «море», але ж на самому початку я знайшов, що ім'я Поліна означає "сонячна".

Отже, як бути із цими іменами? Мені здається, що все ж це різні імена, однак, напевно, так як Полінам часто при хрещенні дають ім'я Пелагея, деякі люди так іх і називають, а отже кликати Поліну Пелагеєю - помилка (бо все ж при хрещенні дівчинку ще можуть назвати Аполлінарією або Павлою).

Comment: Дівчина на Палажку відкликалася? Не ображалася? Значить, її можна так звати. Якими формами яких імен ~правильно~ називати людину - вирішує саме ця конкретна людина.

Comment: Питання - чи це одне і теж ім'я чи це зовсім різні імена?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Із словника-довідника ***"[Власні імена людей](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/ua/elib.exe?Z21ID=&I21DBN=UKRLIB&P21DBN=UKRLIB&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=online_book&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=FF=&S21STR=ukr0001272)"*** *Л. Г. Скрипник, Н. П. Дзятківська*

[image: Поліна]

[image: Палажка]

***Отже, можна зробити висновок, що  це два різні імені.***